# convert e-notation to number within nifi process

Tags: xml, numbers, apache-nifi

I am building a nifi process that ingests .xml files.  I have one .xml where all of the numeric fields are coming through as E-notation, i.e. 1.6777777777E-001.  I am trying to figure out the best approach for taking that .xml file and converting all of the numeric columns and returning an updated .xml?

Answer (score 1):

You could explore using a `ReplaceText` processor with Expression Language math operations to do it, but I think this might be pretty brittle. My suggestion would be an `ExecuteScript` processor which uses Groovy to parse the XML, filter on elements that have a value matching a regex, and then use the Groovy/Java native math libraries to convert this to decimal or whatever other format you want, and output the updated XML. Should be fairly simple to do; there are a [number of examples](http://www.nifi.rocks/using-the-executescript-processor/) available.

If you plan to receive multiple XML documents within a single flowfile, you could also use the [`UpdateRecord`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html) processor with either the reader or writer being `Scripted*` to allow for this transformation.